# Use custom CSS class on JQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a JQuery autocomplete text box. I have a CSS style sheet which defines the theme for on-focus (say .custom-focus) and on-hover (say .custom-onhover) elements. The style sheet can change based on the user theme selection.
I understand that JQuery autocomplete uses classes like "ui-state-focus" to style auto-suggest elements. I need to replace this class with my own class so that it matches with theme and changing the style sheet changes the entire jquery autocomplete theme. (Hence, I cannot simply override the default autocomplete classes). I've achieved this on-hover through following line of code:

```
$(element).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {...})
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
// adding this class gives desired result, and show correct styling on hover
                $(".ui-autocomplete li a").addClass("custom-onhover");
                if (ui != null) {
                    $(element).val(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
```

However, I cannot find a way to get the same experience when the user selects the element through keyboard up/down arrow keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finally able to resolve this by modifying focus to:

```
 $(".ui-autocomplete li a").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
 $(".ui-autocomplete li a").addClass("custom-onhover"); 
 $(".ui-autocomplete li a").removeClass("custom-focus"); 
 var focussedElement = $(".ui-autocomplete .ui-state-focus"); 
 focussedElement.removeClass("ui-state-focus"); 
 focussedElement.addClass("custom-focus");
```